# Using MailMessage with semi cologn seperation

Tags: vb.net, mailmessage

If I manually put my address in for `EmailMessage.To.Add(GetDelimitedField(x, strEmailRep, ";"))`  It sends me the message just fine.  However If I use the code as is below which is using a list that looks like `;email1@mail.com;email2.mail.com`

Then it gives an error that `email address cannot be blank`

Somewhere in `GetDelimitedField` is erasing addresses.  I'm not sure where the problem is actually occurring.  Here is all the code involved with this.

```
strmsg = "LOW STOCK ALERT: Component (" & rsMPCS("MTI_PART_NO") & ") has reached or fallen below it's minimum quantity(" & rsMPCS("MIN_QTY") & ")."
                Dim EmailMessage As MailMessage = New MailMessage
                EmailMessage.From = New MailAddress("noreply@mail.com")
                For x = 1 To GetCommaCount(strEmailRep) + 1
                EmailMessage.To.Add(GetDelimitedField(x, strEmailRep, ";"))
                Next
                EmailMessage.Subject = ("LOW STOCK ALERT!")
                EmailMessage.Body = strmsg
                EmailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High
                EmailMessage.IsBodyHtml = True

                Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("smtp.mycompany.com")

                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = True
                smtp.Send(EmailMessage)


    Public Function GetCommaCount(ByVal sText As String)
        Dim X As Integer
        Dim Count As Integer
        Dim Look As String
        For X = 1 To Len(sText)
            Look = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(sText, X)
            If InStr(X, Look, ";", 1) > 0 Then
                Count = Count + 1
            End If
        Next
        GetCommaCount = Count
    End Function


    Public Function GetDelimitedField(ByRef FieldNum As Short, ByRef DelimitedString As String, ByRef Delimiter As String) As String
        Dim NewPos As Short
        Dim FieldCounter As Short
        Dim FieldData As String
        Dim RightLength As Short
        Dim NextDelimiter As Short

        If (DelimitedString = "") Or (Delimiter = "") Or (FieldNum = 0) Then
            GetDelimitedField = ""
            Exit Function
        End If

        NewPos = 1
        FieldCounter = 1

        While (FieldCounter < FieldNum) And (NewPos <> 0)
            NewPos = InStr(NewPos, DelimitedString, Delimiter, CompareMethod.Text)
            If NewPos <> 0 Then
                FieldCounter = FieldCounter + 1
                NewPos = NewPos + 1
            End If
        End While

        RightLength = Len(DelimitedString) - NewPos + 1
        FieldData = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(DelimitedString, RightLength)
        NextDelimiter = InStr(1, FieldData, Delimiter, CompareMethod.Text)
        If NextDelimiter <> 0 Then
            FieldData = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(FieldData, NextDelimiter - 1)
        End If
        GetDelimitedField = FieldData
    End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the list easier using string.Split:

```
    Dim strEmails = "a@test.com;b@test.com;c@test.com;"

    Dim lstEmails = strEmails.Split(";").ToList()

    'In case the last one had a semicolon:
    If (lstEmails(lstEmails.Count - 1).Trim() = String.Empty) Then
        lstEmails.RemoveAt(lstEmails.Count - 1)
    End If

    If (lstEmails.Count > 0) Then
        lstEmails.AddRange(lstEmails)
    End If
```

Comment: To exclude empty elements you'd be better with `Dim lstEmails = strEmails.Split(";".ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList()`

Comment: Nice recommendation @MrGadget.